# How can I output audio at 48khz?

Tags: rendering, video-sequence-editor, audio

Very noob question, I know, but I can't find the answer on Google or in the manual.

I'm editing a movie file in the VSE, and nothing else. When I want to render it out, the audio is at 44.1kHz, and I'd like it to be 48kHz. I can't find the setting for that anywhere.

The audio I've imported is already at 48kHz.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the 'Scene' buttons, there is an Audio Panel. It has a **Format:** label, under which you can adjust the **Channel count** and **Rate**.

Then you can render Audio from the render panel (also known as **Mixdown**).